# Make an onClick event do something different every other click?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 columns in a table, each with some text at the top and an image below it. I have it so that when someone clicks an image from one of the 3 columns, it enlarges the column, and deletes the other columns using an onClick event. However, I want it so that when I click the image a second time, it brings back the other columns. The problem I'm having is figuring out how to make the onClick event do something different the second time I click it. I've added a couple of (poorly) drawn pictures to help give you an idea. Thanks for your time.

http://i.minus.com/ijFBpWavY386c.jpg

http://i.minus.com/iNExaX8dsN5dK.jpg

Oh, and my current code for the javascript portion (dog, halloween, and comedy are the ID's of each image. And please excuse my terrible (non-existant) indenting; still in a class to learn javascript.):

```
function dog()
{
td12 = document.getElementById('td2');
td12.parentNode.removeChild(td12);

td13 = document.getElementById('td3');
td13.parentNode.removeChild(td13);

td11 = document.getElementById('td1');
td11.style.textAlign = "center";
}
function halloween()
{
td21 = document.getElementById('td1');
td21.parentNode.removeChild(td21);

td23 = document.getElementById('td3');
td23.parentNode.removeChild(td23);

td22 = document.getElementById('td2');
td22.style.textAlign = "center";
}
function comedy()
{
td31 = document.getElementById('td1');
td31.parentNode.removeChild(td31);

td32 = document.getElementById('td2');
td32.parentNode.removeChild(td32);

td33 = document.getElementById('td3');
td33.style.textAlign = "center";
}
```

Comment: As I'm still new to javascript, I don't really have an idea of what to try. I searched for what I put in the title (and slight variations) on Google and here, but couldn't find anything related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a variable that is accessible to all your functions which will tell you what 'mode' your table is in:

```
var allColumns = true;

function comedy() {
    if (allColumns) {
        // ... do stuff here ...
        allColumns = false;
    } else {
        // ... do different stuff here ...
        allColumns = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The other answers were useful too, but this was simplest and didn't require jQuery.

Comment: @Broodyr If the other answers were helpful I'd suggest up-voting them.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using jquery, you can do something like this:

```
function bindImageClick(){    
    $("#imgid").unbind("click");
    $("#imgid").bind("click", function (event) {
        alert("first click");
        $(this).unbind("click");
        $(this).bind("click", function(){
           alert("second click");
           bindImageClick();
        });
    });
}
bindImageClick();
```

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/4zKNJ/3/

Comment: You might want to scope those bind/unbind calls.  Doesn't look like op is using jQuery anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would be pretty straightforward:

```
// Put this within the scope of the <a /> below...
var whichClick = 1;

// The link
<a href="..." onclick="javascript:doSomething(whichClick++ % 2 == 1)">Click Me</a>

// The handler
function doSomething(isOdd){
    // isOdd is true or false, respond accordingly
}
```

Etc.

**EDIT** Tweaked to make function arg a boolean

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Its simply, See fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajnish/j6gWa/)

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Column1</td>
    <td id="click">Column2</td>
    <td>Column3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td{
  border:1px dotted #ccc;
  width:50px
 }
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#click").toggle(
   function(){
     $(this).css('width',200).siblings().hide();;
   },
   function(){
     $(this).css('width',50).siblings().show();;
   }
  );
})
```