# How to make an image toggle 2 divs visibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im trying to make a div swapper type thing and so ill try and describe it for you...

So here are the elements
A image button (the toggle button)
a div, lets call it div A
and another div, div B (this is hidden by default)

Here is a visual representation

```
[Button image] This Is Div A
```

when the button is clicked i want div A's visibility to go "hidden" and its display to be "none"
while div B's visibility sets to "visible", so then pretty much I'm replacing div a with div b

```
[Button image] This Is Div B
```

then when the toggle image is clicked again i want it to swap back again
(Div B's visibility set to "hidden" and it's display set to "none" while Div A's visibility sets to "visable") then i want it to keep going like that so it keeps changing. btw all of this is in a div that is fixed so this will stay at the top of the page.

I tried the following which was based on a answer to this question [Make an onClick event do something different every other click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275831/make-an-onclick-event-do-something-different-every-other-click)

my attempts was:

Html

```
<img id="x" src="img/link here">  
<div id="a">This Is Div A </div>  
<div id="b" style="visibility: hidden;"> This Is Div B </div>
```

Css

```
    function bindImageClick(){  
    $("#x").unbind("click");  
    $("#x").bind("click", function (event) {  
       document.getElementById("b").style.visibility = "visible";  
       document.getElementById("a").style.visibility = "hidden";  
       document.getElementById("a").style.display= "none";  
        $(this).unbind("click");  
        $(this).bind("click", function(){  
       document.getElementById("a").style.visibility = "visible";  
       document.getElementById("b").style.visibility = "hidden";  
       document.getElementById("b").style.display= "none";  
           bindImageClick();  
        });  
    });  
}  
bindImageClick();
```

Any help would be great and for some reason i couldn't indent the code so it had that grey background like me visual representations.

Comment: *btw the "|" represent "<" & ">"* — you can always wrap raw HTML code within code blocks by indenting 4 spaces...

Comment: I did indent 4 spaces and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to swap visibility of A and B every time the image X is clicked, something like the following should work if A is visible by default and B is hidden by default (since you already seem to be using jquery):

```
$("#x").on("click", function(){
    $("#a, #b").toggle();
});
```

And if you must have visibility hidden (jquery toggle uses: display), you could write your own toggle function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#x").on("click", function(){
        myToggle($("#a, #b"));
    });

    function myToggle(divsToToggle)
    {
        divsToToggle.each(function(){
            if($(this).css("visibility") === "hidden")
            {
                $(this).css("visibility", "visible");               
            }
            else 
            {
                $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");   
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but one slight problem, can i get it to toggle the display as well from "none" to "block" vica-versa so it looks like its only using the one line on the screen

Comment: here's something that in the end i wanna create minus the slight problem i said before
[link]http://jsfiddle.net/4zKNJ/16/

Comment: "visibility: hidden" keeps both divs positions on the page. It makes them invisible, but keeps an empty space for them on the page. If you want div A and div B to occupy the same space on the page, you dont need to set the visibility. You just need to set display none/block, which is what the jquery .toggle() function does. So just use that.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at jquery .toggle(), it swaps visibility of selected elements. Your explanation wasn't very clear, but this is the concept.

```
<button id="btn1"></button>
<div id="a"></div>

<button id="btn2"></button>
<div id="b"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#b").hide(); //hide image B by default
    $("#btn1, #btn2").click(function(){
        $("#a, #b").toggle(); //toggle visibility of both images
    });
});
```